# Can mgetty fax a .pdf document?

Tags: mgetty

mgetty is installed on Ubuntu 16.04.  Assume a file of payload.pdf and a target fax number (850)555-5555.

What is the syntax to send the .pdf file to the target fax number?  Any reference (links) to examples are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

According to the online documenation, you need to use [sendfax](http://mgetty.greenie.net/doc/Sending.html#Sending) to actually send a fax using the `mgetty` configuration, and it will only send files in G3 format.

So before sending, you need to [convert](http://mgetty.greenie.net/doc/Convert.html#Convert) any file to this format. The page mentions

```
gs -sDEVICE=dfaxhigh -sOutputFile=/tmp/fax.g3.%d yourdocument.ps
```

to use Ghostscript to "print" as a G3 file. As ghostscript is also able to handle PDF files, I'd assume that should also work for PDF files (but I didn't try; potentially you'll need additional options).

You can script all of this so you don't have to do it each time.

(The above is the result of 5 minutes of googling, and browsing the documentation).

Comment: Thank you for nudging his in the right direction.   Please consider adding to your answer the keywords used to Google and any additional hyperlinks that you feel would assist future readers.